How can I change the DPI attributes of a JPEG file?
Situation: I have a JPEG file with an invalid DPI setting. Preview shows a DPI setting of 1 for both dimensions.
Problem: When trying to print such a JPEG file, it fills a whole DIN A4 page even at 1% printing size. The print dialog does not support fractional size percentages, so the image cannot be sensibly scaled when printing.
Solution attempts: Changing the DPI setting of the JPEG file to a value >= 100 DPI will fix this. The actual value does not even matter much. Any value >= 100 will do.
Remaining question: How can I change the DPI attributes of a JPEG file?

The DPI setting of any JPEG file can be changed using Preview:

Open the image in Preview.
Select Tools -> Adjust Size from the menu.
Change the number next to "Resolution" to 300.
Click OK.
Select File -> Save if you want the change to be permanent.

You can now print the file with any size percentage, since the DPI value is now in a useful range.
